# "...decorated with Injectable" - Angular2

Tags: service, angular

I'm learning the new framework Angular2 from Google through those videos tutorials on Youtube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEM6-TkuOgo

I encounter different kind of errors when I started to learn about Services such as:

> EXCEPTION: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'ContactListComponent'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'ContactListComponent' is decorated with Injectable.
>
> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot resolve all parameters for 'ContactListComponent'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'ContactListComponent' is decorated with Injectable.
>
> angular2-polyfills.js:469 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'ContactListComponent'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'ContactListComponent' is decorated with Injectable. ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
>
> NoAnnotationError {message: "Cannot resolve all parameters for 'ContactListComp…ntactListComponent' is decorated with Injectable.", stack: "Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'ContactL…node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:477:94)"}
>   message
>   :
>   "Cannot resolve all parameters for 'ContactListComponent'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'ContactListComponent' is decorated with Injectable."
>   stack
>   :
>   "Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'ContactListComponent'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'ContactListComponent' is decorated/
>
> angular2-polyfills.js:471 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot resolve all parameters for 'ContactListComponent'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'ContactListComponent' is decorated with Injectable.(…)
>
> angular2-polyfills.js:469 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'ContactListComponent'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'ContactListComponent' is decorated with Injectable. ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: NoAnnotationError {message: "Cannot resolve all parameters for 'ContactListComp…ntactListComponent' is decorated with Injectable.", stack: "Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'ContactL…node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:477:94)"}
>
> angular2-polyfills.js:471 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot resolve all parameters for 'ContactListComponent'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'ContactListComponent' is decorated with Injectable.(…)

I don't understand what the console really means I tried to comment some part of the code to test to check when my code compile or not.

If feel that the problem might be around this part in the contact-list.component.ts:

```
constructor(private _contactService: ContactService) {}
```

And this one too in the contact.service.ts:

```
return Promise.resolve(CONTACTS);
```

I took screenshot of the different TypeScript files in the project: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2b1MQ.jpg

If someone has some clue to debug this code I'm all ears! :)

PS: I can copy/paste the code from the screenshot if this might help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a component `ContactListComponent` like

```
export class ContactListComponent {
  constructor(private contactService:ContactService) {}
}
```

and a service like

```
export class ContactService {
  constructor(private someDep:SomeDependency) {}
}
```

then the ContactService class needs to have an `@Injectable()` decorator like

```
@Injectable()
export class ContactService {
  constructor(private someDep:SomeDependency) {}
}
```

Comment: Hi Günter! Thanks but even when I fix my contact.service.ts compared to your advice with a constructor I got this : > angular2-polyfills.js:332 Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getOptional' of undefined(…) So I've made a Plunker to help check the code : http://plnkr.co/edit/TBeK15tcQlVSkAjRTPSJ

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/85g0L8?p=preview `ngOnInit` had a typo. I also moved your code to a Plunker template of mine.

Comment: Woah exactly! But even when I correct my mistake writing     ngOnInit right I've got a bunch of errors : http://i.imgur.com/vTPdftA.png

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with your imports because the code is working in my Plunker.

Comment: I really don't understand I checked all my Imports several time... Which one could be wrong?

Comment: `ContactService` in `ContactListComponent`.

Comment: `import {ContactService} from './contact.service';` seems to be alright in `contact-list.component.ts`. Also all the files .ts and .js are in the right folder within the right path and found. I just don't get it!

Comment: Do you have consistent file extensions (`.ts`)?

Comment: I guess. Here's my template on localhost : http://i.imgur.com/wtD5tBr.jpg Also updated the Plunker with the template system `.../dev/contacts/` : http://plnkr.co/edit/TBeK15tcQlVSkAjRTPSJ

Comment: I won't be able to help you with configuration issues. I'm not using TS with Angular (only Dart).

Comment: Well thank you very much for the time taken. I wish I could easily fix my problem.

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/angular/quickstart/issues/25 contains anything that helps in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Most of time such problem is because the import for the type specified in constructor parameters is mission or wrong.

Do you import the "ContactService" type in your component.list.ts file?

Something like this:

```
import { ContactService } from './contact.service';
```

Angular2 is responsible to find out which types of instances you want to inject into the constructor. With TypeScript, it's done using the types of parameters you specify but they need to be imported previously into your module.

Dependency injection is done using a decorator: @Injectable for simple classes and by @Component / @Directive for components / directives. But you need a decorator.

Comment: Yes I verified I imported all the file needed also checked twice the path to the repository. I've made a Plunker so this might become more easier to check the code : http://plnkr.co/edit/TBeK15tcQlVSkAjRTPSJ

Comment: Do you have the same problem by removing your `<base href...` in your index.html file? I made it work with this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZiLSZinJdT4VCoOT90AW?p=preview.

Comment: No change with or without `<base href="/">`.